# How to print SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT when using sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, limit

As defined [here](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html), the maximum number of compound select term is `SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT`

How can we get this value when we query a sqlite database using a sql command?

e.g.

```
select SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT from SomeTableSomeWhere
```

or

```
select someFunctionForThisValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I can not answer your directly to your question, but as we know SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT default defined **500**. We can go around with this by using  **SELECT LIMIT, OFFSET** statement to fetch all data in a large table (hope this is want you want)

for example:

```
ID          NAME        AGE         ADDRESS     SALARY
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           Paul        32          California  20000.0
2           Allen       25          Texas       15000.0
3           Teddy       23          Norway      20000.0
4           Mark        25          Rich-Mond   65000.0
5           David       27          Texas       85000.0
6           Kim         22          South-Hall  45000.0
```

With help of count rows

```
sqlite>  SELECT count(*) FROM COMPANY
```

We can select **limit** rows with **offset** to fetch all database table

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM COMPANY LIMIT 3 OFFSET 2;

ID          NAME        AGE         ADDRESS     SALARY
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
3           Teddy       23          Norway      20000.0
4           Mark        25          Rich-Mond   65000.0
5           David       27          Texas       85000.0
```

reference here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_limit_clause.htm